# How does nginx rewrite break flag work?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm trying to set up a "coming soon" temporary page on a website:

```
rewrite ^/(css|img|js)/ -                break;
rewrite ^/$             /comingsoon.html last;
rewrite ^               /?               redirect;
```

But I'm having trouble with the `break` flag: it's supposed to stop processing rewrite rules, but it doesn't seem to work.

My intention here is to:

1. serve all css, img, and js files just as they are;
2. serve the comingsoon.html page in place of the homepage;
3. (temporary) redirect all other pages to the homepage.

The problem is that directive 1. is not working: its URLs fall through to the 3rd rule and are redirected to the homepage, as if the first rule did not have a `break` flag.

The regexp in the first directive does match, because if I replace `break` with `redirect`, I get a 302 to `-`. So this leaves the `break` flag as the culprit.

Am I using it incorrectly?

---

Edit: I solved it with a negative lookahead:

```
rewrite ^/$                 /comingsoon.html last;
rewrite ^/(?!css/|img/|js/) /?               redirect;
```

But I'm still interested in understanding why `break` does not seem to work.

Comment: OMG. Do NOT blindly copy rules from apache. There are much more simple and efficient ways to do it.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Who said I copied rules from Apache? I haven't used Apache in years. This question is about Nginx's `break` flag and why it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I see it by `-` in rewrite.

Comment: @AlexeyTen That `-` means I don't care what it's rewritten to, I just want to stop processing the rules. Is that my mistake here? Maybe you could post an answer if you think you know how to get `break` to work.

Comment: That doesn't work in nginx. I've investigate the problem and writing the answer now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just turned on rewrite log and debug log and found out that your problem is in rewriting to `-`. Unlike Apache, nginx takes it literally and rewrite request URI to string `-`. Then it cannot find any `location` block that matches this URI and uses it's *magic* `configuration ""` that just happens to have all the server `rewrite` rules. So new URI goes through all the rewrite rules again.

Here is the log:

```
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [debug] 7288#7288: *24 http header: "Host: example.com"
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [debug] 7288#7288: *24 http header: "User-Agent: curl/7.47.0"
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [debug] 7288#7288: *24 http header: "Accept: */*"
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [debug] 7288#7288: *24 http header done
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [debug] 7288#7288: *24 event timer del: 4: 1464800021049
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [debug] 7288#7288: *24 generic phase: 0
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [debug] 7288#7288: *24 rewrite phase: 1
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [debug] 7288#7288: *24 http script regex: "^/css/"
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [notice] 7288#7288: *24 "^/css/" matches "/css/asd", client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET /css/asd HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [debug] 7288#7288: *24 http script copy: "-"
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [debug] 7288#7288: *24 http script regex end
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [notice] 7288#7288: *24 rewritten data: "-", args: "", client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET /css/asd HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [debug] 7288#7288: *24 test location: "/"
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [debug] 7288#7288: *24 using configuration ""
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [debug] 7288#7288: *24 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [debug] 7288#7288: *24 rewrite phase: 3
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [debug] 7288#7288: *24 rewrite phase: 4
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [debug] 7288#7288: *24 http script regex: "^/css/"
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [notice] 7288#7288: *24 "^/css/" does not match "-", client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET /css/asd HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [debug] 7288#7288: *24 http script regex: "^/$"
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [notice] 7288#7288: *24 "^/$" does not match "-", client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET /css/asd HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [debug] 7288#7288: *24 http script regex: "^"
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [notice] 7288#7288: *24 "^" matches "-", client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET /css/asd HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [debug] 7288#7288: *24 http script copy: "/"
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [debug] 7288#7288: *24 http script regex end
2016/06/01 19:52:41 [notice] 7288#7288: *24 rewritten redirect: "/", client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET /css/asd HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
```

Fix to initial problem could be as simple as:

```
rewrite ^(/(css|img|js)/.+) $1 break;
```

or

```
rewrite ^/(css|img|js)/ $uri break;
```

So, you **should** care to what you rewrite your URI.